# Ways to mock client + custom runtime api from client side

Tags: testing, client, mock, runtime-api

I have some code in a Substrate client that needs to call one of my runtime apis. I'd like an easy way to mock the client and custom runtime api functions to check that they're called.

Is there an easy way to mock both? I was trying out [substrate-test-runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/test-utils/runtime/src/lib.rs) but don't see a proper way to get it working, and am wondering if there's something better.

Here's a simplified example of a function that I would like to test looks like:

```rust
fn example_call<B, C>(
    client: Arc<C>,
)
where
    B: BlockT,
    C: ProvideRuntimeApi<B> + HeaderBackend<B>,
    C::Api: ConstructExtrinsicApi<B>,
{
    let best_hash = client.info().best_hash;
    client.runtime_api()
        .my_arbitrary_runtime_api_fn(&generic::BlockId::Hash(best_hash));
}
```

Comment: have you found a way my dear friend?

Comment: I forgot about this, but may be worth looking into `mock_impl_runtime_apis` https://docs.rs/sp-api-proc-macro/latest/sp_api_proc_macro/macro.mock_impl_runtime_apis.html